# undefined local variable or method `config' for #<Bundler::Dsl:0x7fe2598d56d8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm following the following tutorial:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/188-declarative-authorization?view=comments

Also Had a go at following the documentation for the gem on Git:

https://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization

But had the same outcome both times which is:

```
mark@ubuntu:~/RoR Projects/blog$ sudo rake gems:install
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/tilt-1.3.3.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-08-25 00:00:00.000000000Z"
rake aborted!
undefined local variable or method `config' for #Bundler::Dsl:0x7fe2598d56d8>
```

I have followed each tutorial to the letter but keep getting the same output so I'm guessing this is a system issue at my end?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're including the gem in rails' old way (before `bundler`) but are using `bundler` and it's `Gemfile`

Add `gem "declarative_authorization"` to your `Gemfile` and it should work as expected.

Comment: ps: you might also want to open a ticket on github to let the authors know that their documentation is outdated, or at least not clear enough